# Avoiding Minor/Major limits errors

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning, limitations, version

I have a SharePoint online document library, and we have enabled minor and major versioning, now some documents will be edited by many users, so we are expecting that the Major (50,000) & Minor (511) versions might be reached.

I know if these limits are met then the users will get errors. So, if I define the following, will we avoid getting any errors as we will guarantee that the limits will never get met:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make the assumption? I've encountered users who met the minor version limit -- education is key, here. Educate your users to perform major version publishing as required, or disable minor versioning.

Comment: because we have  reached the 511 minor versions before.. so my question is if i define limits for major and minor will this avoid getting any errors?

Comment: Nope. They will get an error when attempting to save a 512th version. They must publish a major version to re-start the minor versioning at 1.

Comment: but if we define the minor limit to be 510 then we will never have 512 minor versions so we should not receive any errors.. am i correct?

Comment: No, once you hit whatever the defined minor version limit is (it's just a max of 511), your users will get an error. Turn off minor versioning if this is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the errors you can always limit the versions so that If your list or library exceed the limit set by you, then earlier versions will be deleted when the version limit is reached.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-versioning-works-in-lists-and-libraries-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

[Versioning Best Practices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/versioning-basics-best-practices#best-practices-and-versioning-trivia)

Answer (score 0):

You can set limit the versions to avoid errors.

As the official document says, SharePoint in Microsoft 365 Library Settings allows a range of **100-50000** major versions and each major version allows up to **511** minor versions.

If the threshold is exceeded, SharePoint online will automatically delete the oldest (major/minor) version.

Reference:

- **[How versioning works in lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-versioning-works-in-lists-and-libraries-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247)**